# Is it legal to define override in C++03

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

We have a project that’s using many C++11 facilities, and we thought about this trick to make it compile on C++03.

```
#ifndef USE_CPP0X
#    define override
#endif
```

As far as I know it’s forbidden to define C++ keywords, so is this legal?

Comment: note, that MS VC++ has `override` since MS VC++2005, maybe other C++03 compilers have it as well.

Comment: it's not forbidden, but it is impossible to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is somewhat frowned upon, but it's certainly possible. A better and not so frowned upon variant is to define macros in all large letter, something like

```
#ifndef USE_CPP0x
#  define OVERRIDE
#else
#  define OVERRIDE override
#endif
```

Then remember to use `OVERRIDE` instead of `override` where wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Even more explicit in terms of using 'override' for C++11 and above would be:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#define OVERRIDE override
#else
#define OVERRIDE
#endif
```

The value 201103L is the standard agreed for C++11. The macro __cplusplus is sure to be defined unless you're using an ancient compiler.